# Nothing happens when I click Apply in Eclipse : Windows > Preferences > Android after I specify the sdk location

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make an android project in windows 7. I have installed eclipse and ADT by downloading the zip file and pointing the software source as archive.
Now I need to add the android SDK in Windows->preferences->android. However, when I select the SDK directory there in SDK location and select Apply/OK, nothing happens. The next time I open preferences, the directory is there in the selection dialog (SDK location) , but eclipse just won't load/do anything on clicking Apply.

I have tried to add "\" after it but it didn't work. Also I did what "SDK Readme" file was telling me to do and it didn't work.
What am I supposed to do?
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Maybe everything is in order and you could just start developing?

Comment: Add screen shot of Windows->preferences->android